# vim install error about python2.7 on ubuntu precise 64

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim

I'm trying to install vim on a "vagrant precise 64 VM" but I have the following error message :

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/chef-repo$ sudo apt-get install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgpm2 libpython2.7 python2.7 python2.7-minimal vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny
Suggested packages:
  gpm python2.7-doc binfmt-support ctags vim-doc vim-scripts indent
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgpm2 libpython2.7 vim vim-runtime
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python2.7 python2.7-minimal vim-common vim-tiny
4 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,603 kB/13.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 28.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python2.7 amd64 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-minimal_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Is it a problem with some server access ?

Comment: Did you try the suggestions from the error message, or our sister site Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: No I didn't see it. You're right. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a newbie mistake !

I just only need doing a "sudo apt-get update" to solve the problem.
It was clearly mentionned at the end of the error message.